# Laravel: delete cache entries knowing only a portion of key (not the full key)

Tags: laravel, caching

In short: how can I delete one or more entries from Laravel cache if I don't know the full key but only the beginning or a portion of it?

In long: I'm using a plugin that creates "on the fly" thumbnails and store them in cache, given an original file

i.e. Original file:

```
my-file.jpg
```

Thumb(s) created as they are stored in cache:

```
1459069074s:67:"http://mysite/thumbs/my-file_150x150.jpg";
1455783174s:62:"http://mysite/thumbs/my-file_300x300.jpg";
...
```

When I delete `my-file.jpg` I can also delete related thumbnails with `glob()`, and this is the easy part (I don't have to retrieve the `_widthxheight.jpg` suffix, `glob()` does this for me)... but entries still reside in cache and have no idea on how to delete them using `Cache::forget('key')`...

I can use `Cache::flush()` but this will affects *ALL* cached items, and seems a bit excessive...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Oh, solution found! Since I have thumbnails path (got with `glob()`), I can loop through these paths, retrieve filename with `pathinfo()` and use them as keys to delete cached items